# Updating Clients on any changing of server database

Tags: database, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, networking

I made a program on VS + SQL Server 2008 and launched it on a home network of 3 computers connected through LAN ,The Program fetches data from database and Put it in Dataset ,So users will work on the datasets and any Update ,delete or add on the dataset will update the Database.
The database is on one of the PC (server) which is also running same app,other two PCs are just clients and take there data from the Server database.

My problem is when one PC update the database the other PCs do not know of that update,So for example if one user delete an item and the other user delete the same item ..It will cause an error.

My Question is obvious : How Can I make all PCs updated by any change in Database ?

One Last thing each App talks only with SQL server database on the server and does not talk with other Apps on other PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, and is generally handled (these days) by optimistic concurrency checking - basically, letting the user try to delete/update  but then failing when the row is out of date.

The basic pattern for optimistic concurrency would be to have `rowversion` column with each row. Before doing an UPDATE, you compare the in-memory `rowversion` to the server `rowversion`. If they're mismatched, then you know somebody else has updated the row and it needs to be reloaded. For `DELETE`, I would personally just silently fail the `DELETE` - after all, if a user wants to delete a row, does it really matter if it was deleted beforehand?

Another pattern is pessimistic, which basically locks the row while any user is working on it. This has the obvious downsides of server resources, users walking away from the machine, etc. but can be implemented using either SQL Server locking (eg., `FOR UPDATE`, transactions) or application level locking (eg., checking a shared database table).

With MS SQL Server, you do have one other easy option - [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). This allows SQL Server to notify you (via an event handler) when the results of a query has changed - at which point you can reload the data. As you can imagine, this takes some server resources - but since you only have three clients without a middle tier, it should be ideal.

Comment: Thanks,Actually it is a big project and contains more than 3 clients and it does contain a middle tier ,I will check SqlDependency but I have a question : What big companies do in such instance I mean What is the most effecient way??

Comment: @alihaider - Depends on the requirements. If you're working in a connected scenario (sounds like you are), then you generally don't need to suck down large datasets from your DB. That avoids the problem mostly (different clients are generally working on different rows/tables of the database) and then optimistic concurrency takes care of the rare conflict. If you have a middle tier, you can have the middle tier cache the data and invalidate the cache when updates occur (or use SqlDependency) and distribute updated info to the clients (polling, long-polling, callback, remoted event, etc.)

Comment: It is an inventory system with many POS clients ...What do u think ?

Comment: @alihaider - Sounds like optimistic concurrency would work OK. Load the Products when they look at that screen, load the specific product when they look at details. When they go to save, check the rowversion and if it's different don't allow the save but force a refresh. If they delete and it's already been deleted, force a refresh with or without an warning about the product already being deleted.

Comment: Thank you I will be optimistic to try optimistic type